# Inequality of $(\log(n))!$

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

I have started to learn about asymptotic notations, and I was asked to prove that:

$$c_1(\log_2(n))! \leq n^3 \leq c_2(\log_2(n))!$$

where $c_1$,$c_2$ are constants. I have tried for a really long time to solve it, but I have no clue how to deal with $(\log_2(n))!$

Could someone help please?

Comment: Have you tried Stirling's formula?

Comment: Do you mean $\log_2(n!)?$  If $n=4,$  do you mean$\log_2(24)$ or do you mean $2!$

Comment: Use the commands `\le` $\le$ and `c_1` $c_1$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2701708/5531

Comment: I mean:log(n)*(log(n)-1)*(log(n)-2)*...

Comment: If you mean this, when should the multiplication stop? If $n$ is an integer number $\log_2(n)$ is in general not.

Comment: @user I assume in such cases we should interpret $\log_2(n)$ as $\Gamma(1 + \log_2(n))$

Comment: @User8128 then you should consider editing your post.

Comment: @Surb This post is not his.

Comment: @user ah... good point. Apologies!

Comment: $m! e^{-3m}$ **is not** bounded between two positive constants as $m\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Sterling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), we have
$$\begin{align}
(\log_2n)!
&\approx \sqrt{2\pi\log_2n}\left(\frac{\log_2n}e\right)^{\log_2n} \\
&= \frac{(\log_2n)^{\log_2n}}{n^{\log_2e}}\sqrt{2\pi\log_2n} \\
\end{align}$$
We can write $(\log_2n)^{\log_2n}$ as a power of $n$ by noting that
$$n^{f(n)}=(\log_2n)^{\log_2n} \iff f(n)=\log_2(\log_2n)$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
(\log_2n)!
&\approx a_1n^{\log_2(\log_2n)-a_2}\sqrt{\log_2n} \\
&\gg n^3 \quad \text{as}\;n\rightarrow\infty
\end{align}$$
where $a_1,a_2$ are constants. This means that your original inequality can't be true for asymptotic $n$.